# Adding Filename to a column with your textfile Import

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, ms-access-2010

I have built a form where a user can select one or more files and import them into a single table. When the user selects the file, or yet, multiple files, once the import is complete, I want the file name to be added on each row, of course, related to the correct file.

I am able to setup a query to manually add the filename, but how would I be able to do this in a more automated fashion. For example, if the user selects a file how can I code the SQL query to automatically detect the filename and add it? If the user selects more than one file, how can the query write the correct filename for each row?

Here is my form code:

```
Option Compare Database

'Private Sub Command0_Click()
Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()

'Requires reference to Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library.

   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant

   'Clear listbox contents.
   'Me.FileList.RowSource = ""

   'Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fDialog
      'Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box.
      .AllowMultiSelect = True

      'Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select one or more files"
     .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\ABCCCCC\Desktop\January CMS reports for CCCCC"

      'Clear out the current filters, and add our own.

      .Filters.Clear
      '.Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.MDB; *.ACCDB"
      .Filters.Add "Access Projects", "*.txt"
      '.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      'Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      'user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      'False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
         'Loop through each file selected and add it to the list box.
         For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
           ' Me.FileList.AddItem varFile
         Call InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(varFile)
         Next
      Else
         MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Function InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(FileName As Variant)
    'DoCmd.DeleteObject CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE, "CMS_Reports_2ndSave"
     DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "CMS_Reports_Import", _
    "CMS_Reports_Import", "C:\Users\ABCCCCC\Desktop\January CMS reports for CCCCC\FileName"
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE SET FileName = 'HLTH_COMPRPT_1701011028174_h0062.txt' WHERE FileName is NULL", dbFailOnError
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the code you provided is already working, then this should work for you.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE SET FileName = '" & FileName & "' WHERE FileName is NULL", dbFailOnError
```

If you have issues, it's most likely a syntax issue with the sql string and quotation marks will be the most likely culprit.  If you have problems, put a debug statement in your code so you can see what sql statement is getting generated.  For instance:

```
Function InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(FileName As Variant)

    Dim strSQL as String

    'DoCmd.DeleteObject CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE, "CMS_Reports_2ndSave"
     DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "CMS_Reports_Import", _
    "CMS_Reports_Import", "C:\Users\ABCCCCC\Desktop\January CMS reports for CCCCC\FileName"

    strSQL = "UPDATE CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE SET FileName = '" & FileName & "' WHERE FileName is NULL", dbFailOnError"
    debug.print strSQL

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
End Function
```